# phpmyadmin won't create a database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have never used PHP myAdmin before so I don't know why I am having the troubles that I am. I am trying to create a database, but when I hit "Save" an alert pops up saying, "This is not a number!" and then it won't let me do anything. I am not sure why I am getting this message and I am not sure how to fix it. Here is what I am seeing:

[image]

I only need a database with an id, a last name, and a first name. So I am confused on what all to put in some of these other fields. For instance, do I need anything in "Length/Values" or do I need to make "Default" something else? As far as Collation goes I have no idea what to put in there (if I do need to put something in there). I have completely no idea what "Browser transformation" and "Transformation options" are for. We never talked about this. For `id` I set it to primary so that way no `id`'s will ever be the same. But other than that, I don't know what to do. Any help?

Comment: Varchar fields need length, that is not optional. But phpmyadmin should be telling you where it's got a problem on the form.

Comment: `id` should indeed be `primary`, but I would also recommend `auto_increment`. That way you don't have to specify an `id` when you add a row to the table, and MySQL will automatically assign the next available number. And you also could set the `attributes` to `unsigned` because `auto_increment` will only assign positive numbers. Using unsigned then effectively doubles the available range.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? (It is listed on the main page, and sometimes in the browser title bar, too).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it wants you to define length values for the VARCHAR fields (names)